# Loop Alphabet creating Triangle output

Tags: java

I'm practicing loops right now and one of my assignments is to print the alphabet.  What I managed to produce:

```
for(char alpha = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; alpha++) {
    System.out.print(alpha);
}
```

This prints the alphabet but not in the way that I need it to.
Question: How would I carry the letter's over for each sequence? For example:

```
This is my desired output
a
ab
abc
abcd
abcde
abcdef
abcdefg
abcdefgh
abcdefghi
abcdefghij
abcdefghijk
abcdefghijkl
abcdefghijklm
abcdefghijklmn
abcdefghijklmno
abcdefghijklmnop
abcdefghijklmnopq
abcdefghijklmnopqr
```

Comment: you cannot use `for-each` for this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 26; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.print((char)('a'+j));
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different solutions, but I would recommend you to start from using a StringBuilder class. You can try something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(char alpha = 'A'; alpha <= 'Z'; alpha++) {
    sb.append(alpha)
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
   for(int i = 0; i < 27; i++){
        for(int a = 0; a < i; a++){
        System.out.print((char) (97+a));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Where the output is:

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
abcde
abcdef
abcdefg
abcdefgh
abcdefghi
abcdefghij
abcdefghijk
abcdefghijkl
abcdefghijklm
abcdefghijklmn
abcdefghijklmno
abcdefghijklmnop
abcdefghijklmnopq
abcdefghijklmnopqr
abcdefghijklmnopqrs
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way:

```
public class CharacterPattern1
{
public static void main(String args[])
  {
    for(char c='A';c<='Z';c++)
    {
        for(char d='A';d<=c;d++)
        {
        System.out.print(d+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

/*take a and b initial value as the ascii code of your first alphabet and replace 101 with the last alphabet*/

```
    int a,b;
    for(a=97;a<=101;a++)
    {
        for(b=97;b<=a;b++)
        {
            System.out.print((char)b);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

here is the output for this particular code

`a
ab
abc
abcd
abcde`